# How to stop changing python machine learning result in each run

Tags: python

I'm doing linear regression using python 3.1. I'm using following code

```
from sklearn.model_selection  import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(scaled_df, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1521)
import statsmodels.api as sm
est = sm.OLS(y_train, X_train)
est2 = est.fit()
print(est2.summary())
```

But each time I'm running, I'm getting different result. Can you suggest how can I get same result each time?

Comment: can you give a reproducible example? the coefficients should be the same unless your fit is so unstable. also... that's a pretty old version of python?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what do you mean by reproducible example!! I have shared my code & I can't able to share the data

Comment: if i run your code on another dataset for example iris, I will not get different results. Hence I cannot reproduce your problem. How can anyone see where your problem is?

Comment: OK. Then please ignore it. I thought there was a code problem